# converting YOLO7 model from pytorch python to onnx unity

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, pytorch, barracuda

I am trying to use this yolo7 [model](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7) inside unity with Barracuda, to detect objects (the client at work requested this model specifically).

When running the examples under python, for each frame or image, it exports a line (when passing --save-txt flag) with box dimensions and a number, that I believe correspond to a class or a label of the output type (is it a horse or a car etc).

I exported the model as onnx model, using the code provided in the repo:

```
python export.py --weights yolov7-tiny.pt --grid --end2end --simplify \
--topk-all 100 --iou-thres 0.65 --conf-thres 0.35 --img-size 640 640 --max-wh 640
```

however, I noticed if I import this in unity, it gives warnings about **Resize** not supported, and **end2end Flatten** not supported. Both of which are documented [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.barracuda@1.0/manual/SupportedOperators.html).

I removed --end2end from the export flags, which removed the warning, and for the Resize warning I followed the advice [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/barracuda-release/issues/271)

> Opset 9 would mean Split will be version 2

so I switched this [line](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/export.py#L159) inside **export.py** to use version **9** instead of **12**

This removed all the warnings, however, the shape of the output of the barracuda model once imported into unity is now as follows:
n:1 h:1 w:85 c:25200

So, I have the following questions are:

1- what does the 25200 means? is it the number of labels an output can have?

2- how do I proceed, to extract the boxes and labels, I was expecting the shape to include the number of detections in each image, the label name, the score, the bounding box.

however looking at the source [code](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7/blob/main/detect.py#L100) where I believe the processing is happening, is really messy and I could not figure out how it does this conversion, or the extraction to port it to csharp in unity.

Any hints will be appreciated.